# React native listview: How to stick a row at bottom of the screen when the row reaches bottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

Using `stickyHeaderIndices` (Ref: [stickyHeaderIndices](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#stickyheaderindices)) property of listview in react native, it is possible to stick a scrolling row stick on the top of the listview. Is there any way to do the same behavior for sticking the row at the bottom, when the row reaches the bottom of the list?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue in react-native list view stickyHeaderIndices are stick the row on the top but not on the bottom.